# How to make a button turn around like a card (Flip-Transition) in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I want to simulate the case that if my button (styled like a card) is clicked it turns around and shows a popup-dialog, using a transition like 'flip'. How could I do that with jQuery mobile?
Thnx!

[Here is a jsbin to play around...](http://jsbin.com/arakaj/2/edit)

edit: [just another try, seems to be the right way...](http://jsbin.com/arakaj/5/edit)

Comment: Whats your question? Its already working properly

Comment: You mean like this? http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/4jGjD/

Comment: Hey, thanx for your answers! No, I mean that the card button that has to be clicked to turn around really seems to turn around. So the popup has to cover the card-button and the card button also needs to turn around/flip. Then it would look like the card button flips and the popup seems to be the back of the card button.

Comment: I added this link where I tried some ideas... http://jsbin.com/arakaj/5/edit